# English Auction Compilation Failure. Need help understanding the compile error message

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I need help.
Followed the lecture up to the compile.
Got this failure :

```
ConnectionError (HttpExceptionRequest Request { host = "localhost" port = 8080 secure = False requestHeaders = [("Accept","application/json;charset=utf-8,application/json"),("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8")] path = "/runghc" queryString = "" method = "POST" proxy = Nothing rawBody = False redirectCount = 10 responseTimeout = ResponseTimeoutDefault requestVersion = HTTP/1.1 proxySecureMode = ProxySecureWithConnect } **ResponseTimeout)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Since the message appeared to me to be a timeout issue (I'm a mainframe programmer so I'm crash coursing on understanding thrown error messages on this paltform), I took a chance and simply re-submitted my compile.

It has now compiled SUCCESSFULLY!! Woohoo. I need small successes like this every now and then to keep the hope alive and trudge on.

Comment: You should accept your own answer.